# Java date comparator issue

Tags: java, priority-queue

I'm having issues sorting out my comparator by dates. The date format should be in "dd/MM/yyyy" So I call in my information from an SQL Database and then convert strings to date by doing this:

```
  public void setDeadlineDate(String deadDate) throws ParseException {
        this.d_date = deadDate;
        //convert strings to dates
        formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        convertedDeadlineDate = (Date)formatter.parse(deadDate);
    }
```

I then make a get method below to call for my comparator. I have to examples but there is always a discrepancy in regards to an odd date being out of place and the comparing not being right.

Example 1:

```
  @Override
    public int compare(JobRequest j1, JobRequest j2) {

        if (j1.getConvertedDeadlineDate().before(j2.getConvertedDeadlineDate())) {
            return -1;
        } else if (j1.getConvertedDeadlineDate().after(j2.getConvertedDeadlineDate())) {
            return 1;
        } 
        else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

Example 2:

```
public int compare(JobRequest j1, JobRequest j2){
return j1.getConvertedDeadlineDate().compareTo(j2.getConvertedDeadlineDate());
}
```

both these examples give me issues and my priorityqueue deadlinedate not to be in the correct order as I would like.
in my db they are saved as a varchar in the following format "01/12/2012" , 1st december 2012 as it wouldnt let me use their date function to have it in the english format.

is their a better way for me to convert strings and then compare or am i missing something?

thanks

EDIT:
output getting for ordered dates:

- 05/04/2011
- 16/12/2012
- 18/06/2012
- 17/12/2013
- 17/12/2013
- 16/12/2013
- 17/12/2013
- 14/08/2012
- 19/12/2013

Where I declare PriortyQueue:

```
private Comparator<JobRequest> comparator = new JobQueueComparator(); //calls my comparator
    private PriorityQueue< JobRequest> scheduledJobs = new PriorityQueue<JobRequest>(100, comparator);

    public void addJob(JobRequest job) {
        // now add job to priority queue
        scheduledJobs.add(job); // add jobs from the resultset into queue
    }
```

scheduledJobs.add(job) just populates the queue from a resultset and keeps adding to queue until all fields in database have been read, see below

```
public void populateQueueFromDB() {
        // create priority queue
        try {
            String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/project";
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "root", "nbuser");

            PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT user_id,s_date,e_date,d_date,department,projectname,projectapplication,priority,cores,disk_space,analysis FROM booking");
            ResultSet rs;
            rs = stmt.executeQuery();


            //List<JobRequest> jobList = new ArrayList<JobRequest>();

            while (rs.next()) {
                JobRequest job = new JobRequest();
                User user = new User();
                user.setUserID(rs.getString("user_id"));
                job.setUserID(user.getUserID()); // changes the /user id to the job.setuser id so can call for my queue print.
                job.setStartDate(rs.getString("s_date"));
                job.setEndDate(rs.getString("e_date"));
                job.setDeadlineDate(rs.getString("d_date"));
                job.setDepartment(rs.getString("department"));
                job.setProjectName(rs.getString("projectname"));
                job.setProjectApplication(rs.getString("projectapplication"));
                job.setPriority(rs.getInt("priority"));
                job.setCores(rs.getInt("cores"));
                job.setDiskSpace(rs.getInt("disk_space"));
                job.setAnalysis(rs.getString("analysis"));

                schedulerPriorityQueue.addJob( job );

            }
            schedulerPriorityQueue.printQueue();

            conn.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Got an exception! ");
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }

    }

}
```

PRINT QUEUE:

```
public void printQueue() {
        for (JobRequest jr : scheduledJobs) {

            System.out.print(jr.getUserID() + "-->");
            System.out.print(jr.getStartDate() + "--START-->");
            System.out.print(jr.getEndDate() + "---END-->");
            System.out.print(jr.getDeadDate() + "--DROP-->");
            System.out.print(jr.getDepartment() + "-->");
            System.out.print(jr.getProjectName() + "-->");
            System.out.print(jr.getProjectApplication() + "-->");
            System.out.print(jr.getPriority() + "--PRIORITY-->");
            System.out.print(jr.getCores() + "-->");
            System.out.print(jr.getDiskSpace() + "-->");
            System.out.println(jr.getAnaylsis());

        }
    }
```

Comment: What are the values that not converted properly? It seems that getConvertedDeadlineDate and compare are right.

Comment: @Javier the output i'm getting is in the order as posted above, if I change the returns around the data order changes but just don't know why the comparisons are a bit off

Comment: Can you show how you're declaring your PriorityQueue? Also, how are you getting your output? Removing the head until the Queue is empty?

Comment: @pcalcao added into original, my output is just a printqueue function after my resultset, see above aswell for the adding of jobs

Comment: Can you add just the code for printQueue please? It probably has something to do with this.

Comment: @kieranbop Added an answer, Iterator doesn't guarantee order, you'll have to use the actual methods of Queue to get jobs by priority.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you do: `for (JobRequest jr : scheduledJobs) { ...` you're actually using an implicit `Iterator`, which doesn't guarantee that the items will be returned in order of Priority (defined by your comparator).

Like mentioned above, the documentation states that:

> This class and its iterator implement all of the optional methods of
>   the Collection and Iterator interfaces. The Iterator provided in
>   method iterator() is not guaranteed to traverse the elements of the
>   priority queue in any particular order. If you need ordered traversal,
>   consider using Arrays.sort(pq.toArray()).

Meaning that the order of the jobs in queue and the order of the iterator isn't necessarily the same.

If you just need to list the jobs, use the `Arrays.sort` approach mentioned in the docs.

If you want to make sure that your PriorityQueue is working, you'll have to use it as one, doing something like:

```
while(!scheduledJobs.isEmpty()) {
     ... = scheduledJobs.poll();
     //print, do whatever
}
```

Keep in mind that this removes the elements from the Queue, and should only be used for testing purposes, or to actually handle the jobs as you need. But this should show you the dates in the actual Priority order.

It seems to me that there's some confusion on how the `PriorityQueue` should be used. I would say that the regular use case would be something like:

- Add elements to the queue
- Define a method to handle the "jobs" (each element), in the queue
- While the queue isn't empty, get each element using `poll` (returns the smallest), and do whatever you need to do with it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, Not the best with java as you can see from structure of my code above etc, from what I've currently implemented, after adding the jobs from the resultset into the queue, would I change that to adding the jobs to an array then making a queue?

Comment: It depends on what you need. If you just need to process them in order, use the PriorityQueue as you are using, but instead of traversion, just `poll` and handle each of the objects inside. That's how a PriorityQueue is meant to be used.

Comment: the aim was to put it all into a queue, then sort the queue depending on deadline date, then I will be picking things off the top of the queue after i've got the dates sorted onto some kind of execution queue (not that far yet), right i'll give it a go but need to do some reading first, this traversion bit? where have i done that in my code?

Comment: thanks very much for the answers and pointers, my heads about to explode, took me ages to get that working.. Learn something new every day

Comment: if I wanted to take items off my queue based on the size of "memory" they require, using the .poll method then put them into something like an FIFO execution stack and stop taking from the queue when the stack has reached its memory limit from x amount of jobs, how would I implement such a thing?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation of PriorityQueue says that

> The Iterator provided in method iterator() is not guaranteed to
>   traverse the elements of the priority queue in any particular order.
>   If you need ordered traversal, consider using
>   Arrays.sort(pq.toArray())

.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html

Answer (score 0):

This works perfectly for me:

```
public class JobRequest implements Comparable<JobRequest> {

    static final DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    Date convertedDeadlineDate;

    Date getConvertedDeadlineDate() {
        return convertedDeadlineDate;
    }

    public JobRequest(String deadDate) {
        try {
            convertedDeadlineDate = (Date) formatter.parse(deadDate);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(JobRequest j) {
        return this.getConvertedDeadlineDate().compareTo(
                j.getConvertedDeadlineDate());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<JobRequest> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new JobRequest("10/10/2010"));
        list.add(new JobRequest("09/09/2009"));
        list.add(new JobRequest("11/11/2011"));
        list.add(new JobRequest("08/08/2008"));

        Collections.sort(list);

        for (JobRequest j : list) {
            System.out.println(formatter.format(j.getConvertedDeadlineDate()));
        }
    }

}
```

Which results in the output:

```
08/08/2008
09/09/2009
10/10/2010
11/11/2011
```

Comment: If the OP needs a PriorityQueue, your answer diverges from that entirely.